# Format of axes labels in gnuplot

Tags: format, label, gnuplot

I am using and old script to produce new plots.
In the old figures, the labels on the axes were something like :
1e-8, 2e-8, 3e-8, etc...
In the new plot, I now get something like :
1x10-8, 2x10-8, etc...
How could I go back to the previous format ?

Comment: `set format x "%.0te%1T"`

Comment: @Michael, works fine, thanks

Comment: The default format used to be `%g` and was changed to `%h` in gnuplot 5.